# How to OneToMany unidirectional relationship (Spring boot + JPA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get results from an unidirectional OneToMany relation in Spring Boot.

This is my "Brand" entity

```
@Entity
@Table
class Brand {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id 

@Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
private String name 

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_model", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Model> models  // Listado de modelos

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "fecha_alta")
private Timestamp fechaAlta // Fecha de alta

*getters and setters*
```

And this is my "Model" entity

```
@Entity
@Table
class Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id // Identificaodr único del modelo

@Column(nullable = false, name="id_model")
private Long idModel // Identificador de la comisión

*getters and setters*
```

I want to get the list of "brands" with their respective models using repository, service and controller by Spring Boot and I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Simply create a query. Or don't I understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

BrandRepository.class

```
interface BrandRepository implements CrudRepository<Brand,Long> {
  @Query("SELECT b FROM Brand b JOIN FETCH b.models")
  List<Brand> getAll();
}
```

BrandService.class

```
@Service
class BrandService {
  private final BrandRepository brandRepository;

  public BrandService(BrandRepository brandRepository) {
    this.brandRepository = brandRepository;
  }

  List<Brand> getAll() {
    return brandRepository.getAll();
  }
}
```

BrandController.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/brands")
class BrandController {
  private final BrandService brandService;

  public BrandController(BrandService brandService) {
    this.brandService = brandService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public List<Brand> getAll() {
    return brandService.getAll();
  }
}
```

As a suggestion,

Brand.class:

-@Table remove annotation. (There is no need if you will not name the table. Creates a table named class by default.)

-models field, remove fetch strategy. (@OneToMany default fetch, LAZY)

These articles can help you understand the answer:

[Working with Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

[Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

[Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)